# How to avoid code duplication when using multiple view folders in Rails (mobile version)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the mobile version of some of my view templates in a different view folder (say app/views_mobile), as shown here:

http://scottwb.com/blog/2012/02/23/a-better-way-to-add-mobile-pages-to-a-rails-site/

It all works fine but led me to some nasty code duplication (duplicated registration forms whose fields may change over time...).

Does anyone have experience in this kind of situation? 
I'd like to know if partial sharing is the way to go in this multiple-view-folder scenario and how to do it (I haven't found any tips on this).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use responsive web design libraries. Eg. [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

If you use it properly, you dont need to create separate views since it will automatically adjust your templates based on the size of the screen through media queries.

Happy coding! :D

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I do need to separate views. All my views are responsive, but some of them need to load and style some specific contents differently. If I did these views responsive, all data should be loaded and then presented accordingly and the would mean too much loading for mobile devices.